# How to get a date part from a string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datepart

'UNK-JAN-2015'
This is my date value.
UNK refers Unknown value.
Now I need to get only month from that.
Is there any way to find it......

Comment: You're actually storing the dates as strings?

Comment: is it date time column ?

Comment: YOu are storing dates as string so You can use the `Right`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx I will advice you to use the proper datatypes for the data.

Comment: If I want to get only month .................?

Comment: development is easier when requiements are frozen ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
RIGHT(DateString, 4) [Year], 
LEFT(RIGHT(DateString, 8), 3) [Month] 
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `SUBSTRING`

**Query**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('UNK-JAN-2015',LEN('UNK-JAN-2015')-3,4);
```

Using `RIGHT`

**Query**

```
SELECT RIGHT('UNK-JAN-2015', 4);
```

To get Month from the given string,

**Query**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('UNK-JAN-2015',5,3) AS [Month];
```

Comment: please view the edit to the post and update accordingly, as the OP s now requesting the month

Answer (score 0):

If you instead  want to find the last token separated by `-` you could use this:

```
SELECT DT = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@DateString),0,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(@DateString))))
```

This also returns 2015, so the text behind the last dash. So it does not only return the last 4 characters. With  `UNK-JAN-2015/02/09` it returns `2015/02/09`.

Edit: If you want the middle part, the month, you could use:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@DateString, CHARINDEX('-',@DateString)+1,LEN(@DateString)-CHARINDEX('-',@DateString,CHARINDEX('-',@DateString))-(CHARINDEX('-',@DateString)+1))
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. How to get only month value?

Comment: @Jasper: i've edited my answer. Maybe there's an easier approach but that works and is completely dynamic so only looks for the `-`.

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
declare @text varchar(100)
set @text='UNK-JAN-2015'

set @text= '<r>'+ REPLACE(@text,'-','</r><r>') + '</r>'

select i.value('r[2]','varchar(10)') AS Year 
from (select cast(@text as xml) xml)out CROSS APPLY out.xml.nodes('/') x(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an actual month value, rather than simply taking the 3 characters that make up the month portion of the string, you can convert it to a date using some string manipulation and extract the month from it:

```
DECLARE @val NVARCHAR(15) = 'UNK-JAN-2015'

SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(@val, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@val, 5, 3)) AS TheDate,
    MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(@val, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@val, 5, 3))) MonthNumber,
    DATENAME(MONTH,
           CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(@val, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@val, 5, 3))) [MonthName]
```

**Output:**

```
TheDate                   MonthNumber   MonthName
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000   1             January
```

This assumes that the value is always in the same format: `XXX-MMM-YYYY` (where XXX is some prefix)